# Convert a hexadecimal to a float and a float to a hexadecimal

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

I am creating a C program to convert a hexadecimal to a float and a float to a hexadecimal.

I have the solution sorted out in my mind, but I have a couple of questions I would like to ask.

The way I am going to solve this is:

First recognize the input as a float or a hexadecimal by scanning the array and checking if the first 2 indices of the string input is 0x, then it is a hexadecimal.
My question at this point is, can I for example write a code as such:

```
char* string;
scanf(%s, string);
if(string[0] == '0' && string[1] == 'x')
{
printf("The number you've entered is a hexadecimal and the corresponding float is:");
```

Here I don't really know what placeholders are there in C like %x. Would %f work for a string?

I tried doing this, but for some reason, my compiler does not read the condition and skips it.
Also, I know printf() works for double. so if I cast the double by an (unsignedint), I can convert a float to a hexadecimal if I do this:

```
float f;
printf("Enter float");
scanf("%f", &f);
printf("hex is %x", *(unsigned int*)&f);
```

This works perfectly fine.

In the program I have to write it says my program has to produce an error if hexadecimal arguments are out of range.(As in too many hexadecimal digits). But what is that normally supposed to mean? Based on what? The IEEE 754 format ? 32 bit number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hexadecimal floating number becomes available since C99.

e.g.

```
char *input = "0xf.1p2";//
float x = 0xf.1P2;//60.25
printf("%f\n", x);
printf("%8.7a\n", x);
float f;
sscanf(input, "%f", &f);
printf("%f\n", f);
printf("%8.7a\n", f);
/* result
60.250000
0xf.1000000p+2
60.250000
0xf.1000000p+2
*/
```

*Based on what? The IEEE 754 format ? 32 bit number?*

```
hex is %x", *(unsigned int*)&f);
```

The above is what you want to view the internal representation.

IEEE standard is used for the internal representation in the C implementation of many, but that is optional.